# Why Aren't the _construct() Methods on EAV Resources and Collections Declared as Abstract Methods?

Tags: php, oop, magento

I've been poking around the bowels of Magento systems code.  For "regular" model resources, Magento's `_construct` initialization convention has been declared abstract

```
File: Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Abstract.php
abstract protected function _construct();
```

This makes sense, as it forces developers creating their own Model resources to call the _construct function, which does the necessary initialization.

However, the same convention/need exists for EAV Model Resources and their collections, but the `_construct` method is **not** abstract in those hierarchies. Does anyone know the reasoning behind this? Are there cases where you don't need a `_construct` method on these models?  Or is this a historical backwards compatibility thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is left in for backward compatibility issues ;)